# How can I use jQuery to select and act on an element without a guard clause?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am rewriting some old JavaScript with jQuery and would like to know how to write it more cleanly.

The script I'm starting with is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < form1.elements.length; i++) {
    var element = form1.elements[i];
    alert(element.id)

    if (Left(element.id, 15) === 'selHeaderFilter' || 
        element.id === 'ddlHierarchy1') {
        garrHeaderState[element.id] = element.selectedIndex
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure why it's been written as it was, but I *think* it is simply trying to add 2 elements to an array (that's declared globally).

My first stab at this has given me:

```
var hierarchy = $('[id$=ddlHierarchy1]');
var headerFilter = $('[id*="selHeaderFilter"]');

if (hierarchy)
    garrHeaderState[hierarchy.attr('id')] = hierarchy.val();

if (headerFilter)
    garrHeaderState[headerFilter.attr('id')] = headerFilter.val();
```

But I don't really like the process of declaring hierarchy just so that if it exists I can add its selected index to the array. Is there a better way of writing this code?

Comment: Even if there are no obejcts return, jQuery will return an empty collection which will cause your statement to evaluate to true. Checkout this for confirmation: http://jsfiddle.net/2JCpf/

Comment: Are you saying my guard clause is effectively not-effective?

Comment: I had to rewrite another function:
    for (i = 0; i < document.form1.elements.length; i++) {
        if (document.form1.elements[i].type === "select-one") {
            if (document.form1.elements[i].id.slice(0, 15) === 'selHeaderFilter') {
                document.form1.elements[i].selectedIndex = 0
            }
        }
    }

Comment: to:
var headerFilter = $('[id*="selHeaderFilter"]');

    if (headerFilter)
        headerFilter.val(0);

Comment: In effect I am saying that it is effectivey not effective ;-)

Comment: Would/should I do something like: $('[id*="selHeaderFilter"]').val(0); instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the each function of jQuery.

```
$('[id$=ddlHierarchy1], [id*="selHeaderFilter"]').each(function(){
    var item = $(this);
    garrHeaderState[item.attr('id')] = item.val();
});
```

Comment: Pretty similar to my answer, if performance is an issue at all, then caching `$(this)` in a variable runs faster as done here

Comment: Yes, this is funny how we both write alsmost the same piece of code at the same time. Obviously, you are right with catching both apttern, so I'll edit my answer to fit advantages of both.

Comment: Or you could have just done `garrHeaderState[this.id] = $(this).val();`, and there would be no need for caching, making it even faster (in theory at least).

Comment: @DarthJDG I have the habbit of alway use jQuery or similar tools to get/put informations. In this case, this is very trivial and you are right, but in many case, you can go throw cross browser mess, and this is damn hard to test/ensure that you have no regression. Using jQuery's function is a way to rely on solid stuff, broadly testd.

Comment: This certainly makes it much neater, I like the caching of item

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
$('[id$=ddlHierarchy1], [id*="selHeaderFilter"]').each(function(){
    garrHeaderState[this.id] = $(this).val();
})
```

Edit: updated according to edits from other post to avoid caching and duplicate running of jQuery function